# htaccess- unable to remove file extension from url php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying the following rules to remove file extension from file name but the problem is it is showing that it is removed but when I login again it is not redirecting to my home page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase \

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Thank You

Comment: What url are you entering in your browser's location ?

Comment: www.example.com/homePage.php

Comment: Why are you using a backslash in the RewriteBase directive?

Comment: May be this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: i tried all this but no gain

Comment: Are you doing a form POST while trying to login?

Answer (score 1):

In your redirection just type in page name with no extension, eg.  **header('Location: index');** or **redirect_user('index');**  and use the code below in your .htaccess file. now the link on the browser will be say "localhost/index"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your rules are just a little bit off. You are using `THE_REQUEST` to redirect php extension to non php extension but you are not using a `/` after `%1` in the rewriterule so when the next rule is read it is not matching because it will only internally redirect if there is a `/` in that rule. So either add a forward slash after %1 in the second rule or make the backslash optional in the last rule. I would just make it optional in last rule so it will match either way.

Try this update and see how it works.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /([^&\ ]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? we have no idea how your setup is. What do you mean it's not working? Do you get an error? Also what is the EXACT url you are using? And what do you mean you can't login? What happens?